# Function for writing text file (.obj) data to python list fills list with last element in data file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to save co-ordinate information of a .obj file to a multidimensional python list. Each element of the list "cube" is 8 sets of 3D co-ordinates.

The code was working fine until I made it into a function. The problem seems to be in the for loop I made for parsing the data, but I cannot see what's wrong.

The data file looks like this (only pasted the first two objects (cubes, since they are all cubes)): https://pastebin.com/U7dmCsC3

```
def read_obj(file, filepath):
    # count number of distinct objects (cubes)
    o = 0
    for line in fyle:
        if line[0] == "o":
            o += 1
    print("number of cubes =", o)

    # generate array with size = number of cubes
    vec = [0.0] * 3
    arr = [vec] * 8
    cube = [arr] * o
    # each element of cube is an array of
    # the 8 co-ordinates that make up the cube
    i = -1
    j = 0
    for line in open(filepath):
        # 
        vec_line = line.split(" ")
        if line[0] == "o":
            i += 1
            j = 0
        if line[0] == "v" and line[1] == " ":
            cube[i][j] = [float(vec_line[1]),
            float(vec_line[2]),float(vec_line[3])]
            j += 1

    return cube
```

To run it,

```
cube = read_obj(fyle, filepath)
```

Where filepath is chosen with tkinter, and

```
fyle = open(filepath,"r")
```

Every time the letter "o" is read the function should write the following co-ordinates to cube[i] in the for loop, until the next "o" and then it goes on to cube[i+1] and so on. The problem I have is that every row of cube is the same - the co-ordinates of the last object in the data file.

Comment: "The problem seems to be..." - what _is_ the problem? Does your code error out? If so, please include the full error message in your post. Does it give wrong results? If so, please include them and the expected results in the post.

Comment: The first thing that sticks out is that you didn't do a proper indentation in the function. And as @ForceBru said, you need to provide more details on the problem you are facing.

Comment: The problem is described in the title. The array returned by my function is the same set of co-ordinates (cube[0] == cube[1] etc.), which happen to be the co-ordinates of the last cube in the data file.

The indentation got messed up pasting it here, but is correct in my code.

edit: updated my post

Comment: If I write the exact same code but not in a function it works as expected. Anyone know why this could be? Literally just the same code but not as part of a function.